# MediaFoundationReader throws exception when playing recorded .wav file

Tags: c#, naudio

Basically I'm recording what is heard on my speakers like that

```
speakersWaveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(); //class variable
waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(filepath, speakersWaveIn.WaveFormat); //class variable
speakersWaveIn.DataAvailable += speakersWaveIn_DataAvailable;
speakersWaveIn.RecordingStopped += speakersWaveIn_RecordingStopped;
speakersWaveIn.StartRecording();
```

`speakersWaveIn_DataAvailable`

```
waveFileWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
waveFileWriter.Flush();
```

and on key-press

```
speakersWaveIn.StopRecording();
waveFileWriter.Dispose();
```

which works perfectly. I am able to play the produced wav.-file with the `Windows Media Player`.

However, when trying to play the file via

```
MediaFoundationReader reader = new MediaFoundationReader(filePath);
```

I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: HRESULT: 0xC00D5212`.

Comment: can you check what actual WaveFormat the WAV file has? WASAPI likes to use WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE, but is better to just use regular WaveFormat to make it playable. NAudio has a `ToStandardWaveFormat` method on the `WaveFormat` you can use to convert.

Comment: By using a `WaveFileReader` instead of a `MediaFoundationReader` it works and it says as waveFormat `IEEE`. I then tried `AudioFileReader` since I need to play mp3 and aac as well and it worked. Is there any downside to using `AudioFileReader` over `MediaFoundationReader`?

Comment: not really. `AudioFileReader` is just a wrapper and will use `WaveFileReader` if its a WAV file. Not sure why `MediaFoundationReader` would have a problem though